Is it safe to use cherry pick in this scenario?
I work on a project where I can't merge the develop branch into master. The way to collaborate is to create branches from master, then merge into develop and publish. Confirmed the functionality is fine. The new branch is merged into its parent master branch and published. In this context
From a master branch create branch PL-442 and add a couple of commits. Then merged PL-442 into develop branch and publish. Then in develop I made a couple of commits that in context belong to PL-442 and publish develop again. The thing is that now I have to mix PL-442 in master to later publish master. But I have the commits in develop. It is safe to use cherry pick to obtain the relevant develop commits in PL-442 and now be able to mix to master.
Is this solution safe for this scenario?
I hope I have explained myself adequately

What is develop used for? develop is a shared branch (others use it too), isn't it? Do you use Pull Requests?

Short answer is, yes, cherry-picking these two commits will work here with the caveat that if there are changes made by others in develop in the meantime it may work but it may not.
If after you then merge PL-442 to master it will look like you did the normal procedure, without making the mistake.
The history after cherry-pick x 2 and (pl-422->master) will look something like this:
master -----------------------------------      <has ABCD
       \                              /
pl-422  -- A - B -----------C----D----          <has ABCD
                   \       /    /
                  merge  ch-p ch-p    
                     \   /   /
develop ----------------C--D--------------      <has ABCD

Notes:

s this question proves, the workflow is error-prone and should be revisited.
There are other ways of dealing with this,  and many of them would rewrite history on the branches. I would advise against that until you gain more experience.

